# UIPickerView (FlipsideViewController) display value in MainViewController

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, selectedvalue

Using the flipsideViewControllerDidFinish method in my MainViewController class, I can display the values of various controls that are on my subview FlipsideViewController. e.g. a UIDatePicker by doing the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatFromDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatFromDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *formatToDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatToDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *fromDateSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatFromDate stringFromDate:controller.fromDate.date]];
NSString *toDateSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatToDate stringFromDate:controller.toDate.date]];

lblFromDate.text = fromDateSelected;
lblToDate.text = toDateSelected;
```

I am trying to get the value of a UIPickerView to display on the MainViewController. I can display the value on the FlipsideViewController by using the following event method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    customDateSelected = [customDates objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"Selected Date: %@. Index of selected Date: %i", customDateSelected, row);
}
```

Just don't know how to display that value in the MainViewController.